# error: ‘Player’ has not been declared with included Player.h

Tags: c++, include

I got a Game-Class

```
#include "../player/Player.h"

class Game {
protected:
    GameBoard board;
    std::vector<Player*> allPlayer;
//other stuff
};
```

But when I try to compile, I get a `error: ‘Player’ has not been declared` and `error: template argument 1[and 2] is invalid`.

I have absolutely no idea, how to debug this error. I did no spelling errors and my IDE( CLion ) doesn't seem to have any problems with anything (wrong include paths etc..) either.

Soooo, what went wrong? ^^

edit: Player.h

```
#include "../game/moveTypes.h"
#include "../board/GameBoard.h"

class Player {
protected:
    sign color;
public:
    sign getColor() const;
public:
    Player(sign playersColor);
    virtual move generateInput() = 0;
};
```

Comment: And what's the content of `Player.h`? Perhaps this header declares the type `Player` to be in a namespace? If this header file containing `Game` never actually dereferences `allPlayer` you could get away with just a forward declaration of the class, but there's something more fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: Or `Player.h` contains (directly or indirectly through another include) `#include <Game.h>` which is a circular dependency.

Comment: That's possible too, in which case forward declaration is the correct solution. But without seeing the contents of `Player.h`, we can only speculate.

Comment: player.h is added, and I clicked me through the header and as far as i can see, i didn't circled anything

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ include guards".  Employ them and see if issue goes away.

Comment: My IDE creates them automaticly